# How to see exceptions in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, debugging, logging, android-studio

When I run my project on Android Studio, bottom part will always show what kind of exception is thrown. I clicked some buttons that I do not remember, so now it shows me Event Log. When I run my projects on emulator/device now it shows me that:

> 14:18:06 Gradle build finished in 3 sec
>
> 14:20:18 Gradle build finished in 3 sec
>
> 14:20:31 Gradle build finished in 3 sec
>
> 14:20:32 Session 'app': running
>
> 14:21:03 Gradle build finished in 3 sec
>
> 14:21:04 Session 'app': running

Now I don't know what kind of exception is thrown. What I must to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `Alt + 6` to open the **Android DDMS** window or alternatively press `CTRL + Shift + A` and enter `Android`. This will open the `Find Action...` dialog - a pretty neat feature in order to find/run things quickly.

[image: Find Action Dialog Android Studio]

#### Edit:

Usually there's also a button somewhere on the left/right/bottom side where you can open the Android DDMS, Terminal, Event Log etc. with a click. See the following screenshot:

[image]